# Howto enable spellchecking in Canadian English (incl in LibreOffice) for all users / system-wide

Tags: libreoffice, system, administration, language-support

It seems that no one gets the benefit of spell-checking in LibreOffice on our Ubuntu computers.
We have them generally set up with Canadian English as default languages, but apparently there is no spell checking for Canadian English.

The fix seems to be for each new user to do the following, within LibreOffice:

Go to Tools/Options/Language Settings/Languages.
 For "Default language for documents," pick English (USA) or
English (UK).

It allows dozens of flavours of English, BUT spelling is
disabled for all the ones that don't have the little blue tick
ABC icon beside them.

That is not good, since in Canada we have spelling that is more flexible than US or UK.
However, my question is how to set this up for everyone, at the system level, so that each user does not need to figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canadian spell-checking is available.

```
sudo apt-get install hunspell-en-ca
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @edwin: True. But it provides a solution to the problem. Isn't that more important?

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong. But that package is installed, yet the options for me do not include Canadian English with spellchecking: viz http://barringtonleigh.net/tmpenglish.png

Comment: @ChristopherBarrington-Leigh: Strange; for me English (Canada) is marked as an option. Which Ubuntu version are you using? You could also try to reinstall the Canadian spellchecker through: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall hunspell-en-ca`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thank you! (1) Well, maybe I needed to log out or even reboot. Now the Canada option has the ABC by it. Also, a guest account has spell-checking working when they start up, and in Canadian. (2) How can I edit my question so that your response answers it? (@edwin), (3) Shouldn't hunspell-en-ca be installed by default if my stated location is in Canada when I install? Should I post an Ubuntu bug? (For two years, the install bug which makes Montreal not selectable on the world map has gone unfixed, but I can still try...)

Comment: @ChristopherBarrington-Leigh: (2) Maybe: "Howto enable spellchecking in Canadian English" (3) The bug https://launchpad.net/bugs/1294858 should take care of it. Please feel free to add a comment to the bug report. ;)